# Is it better to make table for each type of users or one table for all of them with Type column?

Tags: database-design

I've about 10 types of users which most of them have different properties.
Which is better:
1- Make a big table with all the properties from all the types in it.
2- Make a different table for each type and one common table for the common properties ?.

Answer (score 0):

It depends totally in what you want to do with these different types. One suggestion: Split the tables and make a union-view with the shared columns.